# Does conversion constructor create an object and destroys it if there is no assignment operator in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a somehow basic question regarding the conversion constructors and assignment operators. I can't find a similar question but maybe I am searching wrongly.
Anyway.. I had made a class like this

```
class String
{
private:
//    enum { SZ = 80 };
    static const int SZ = 80;
    char str[SZ]; //array
public:
    String() //constructor, no args
    {
        cout << "Default constructor called, p_str = " << (void*)str << endl;
        strcpy(str, "");
    }
    String( char s[] ) //constructor, one arg
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor called, p_str = " << (void*)str << endl;
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    void display() //display string
    {
        cout << str << endl;
//        cout << "str ptr = " << (void*)str << endl;
    }
    void concat(String s2) //add arg string to
    { //this string
        if( strlen(str)+strlen(s2.str) < SZ )
            strcat(str, s2.str);
        else
            cout << "\nString too long";
    }
    void SetString(char* strToSet)
    {
        strcpy(str, strToSet);
    }
//    void operator =(const char* strCpy)
//    {
//        cout << "Copy assignemnt called..." << endl;
//        strcpy(str, strCpy);
//    }
    ~String()
    {
        cout << "Destructor called..." << endl;
    }
    void* GetStrPtr()
    {
        return (void*)str;
    }
};
```

and in the main:

```
    String myStr1 = "Hello Hello";

    void* old_str_ptr = myStr1.GetStrPtr();
    cout << "old_str_ptr = " <<old_str_ptr << endl;

    myStr1 = "hello World!!";
    cout << "old_str_ptr = " <<old_str_ptr << endl;
    void* new_str_ptr = myStr1.GetStrPtr();
    cout << "new_str_ptr = " <<new_str_ptr << endl;
    myStr1.display();
    cout << (char*)old_str_ptr << endl;
    cout << (char*)new_str_ptr << endl;
```

This is the output I got:

```
Copy constructor called, p_str = 0x62fdd8
old_str_ptr = 0x62fdd8
Copy constructor called, p_str = 0x62fe28
Destructor called...
old_str_ptr = 0x62fdd8
new_str_ptr = 0x62fdd8
hello World!!
hello World!!
hello World!!
Destructor called...
```

Can someone explains what happens exactly at this line in main:

```
myStr1 = "hello World!!"
```

As I can see that it calls the conversion constructor (as the assignment operator is commented) and the address of "str" array is changed then what I don't understand is that the destructor is called and the address is returned back as seen in the output.

Comment: Please post the output of your program in text form instead of an image.

Comment: You don't have copy constructor in your code, the `String( char s[] )` is conversion constructor not copy constructor.

Comment: @metablaster: yes sorry my mistake.. ok I can't understand the behavior still with using the conversion constructor

Comment: `String myStr1 = "Hello Hello";` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) but it doesn't necessarily have to make a copy or use the assignment operator. Code is a description of behaviour, not a list of instructions, and the modern compiler is a smart tool. If it sees a path to give the requested behaviour, a `String ` containing "Hello Hello", with less work, it'll take it.

Comment: @RSahu: I edited the question to have the output in text also edited "copy constructor" to "conversion constructor"

Comment: @user4581301 It cannot be copy-initialization because `myStr1` was previously-declared. This is copy/move-assignment from a temporary.

Comment: Ja. just spotted the `myStr1 = "hello World!!";` later in the code. Wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @user4581301: Okay I was asking about this line ```myStr1 = "hello World!!";```. as I don't understand the behavior exactly.

Comment: It's all my mistake, Mohamad. The only reason I've left the comments up there is removing them makes cdhowie's comment on the mistake look goofy.

Comment: @user4581301: no worries :).. thx for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `myStr1 = "hello World!!";` the two types are not compatible, so assigment would normally not be possible. However, the compiler notices that you have an implicit conversion constructor that accepts a pointer-to-`char` and so it invokes this constructor to create a temporary object from which assignment can happen.  This is the sequence of events:

- A temporary `String` object is constructed, invoking `String("hello World!"")`.
- The temporary is either copy-assigned (C++ < 11) or move-assigned (C++ >= 11) to `myStr1` (you don't overload assignment so you don't observe this step in your output).  Whether copy-assigned or move-assigned, the relevant compiler-generated assignment operator performs a simple memberwise value copy in this case since the members can't be moved.
- The temporary is destructed.

The location of `str` does not change simply because it can't: it's an array member of the class, meaning its storage is directly allocated as part of `String` objects.  `str` evaluated as a pointer points to a region of memory *within* the `String` object.

The implicit move-assignment operator simply copies the *contents* of the source object's `str` array into the target object's `str` array.

You see a different value on the second constructor message because this is a different object being constructed, and therefore its `str` member exists in a different memory location. However, this object is destructed after its value is copied into the `myStr1` object.

Comment: Some of this isn't really true since C++17, in which the rules of temporary materialisation are more aligned with the abstract machine that C++ is than some sequence of steps on a physical computer. In C++17, the temporary in step one doesn't get constructed then copy/move-assigned; it literally comes into existence inside the assignment operator.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings From what I'm reading, temporary materialization would occur during copy-initialization, but that is not what is happening here. `myStr1` is already initialized. Unless I'm missing something, the elision that temporary materialization seeks to facilitate is therefore not possible in this situation.

Comment: It's not "elision". It's a delay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146960/temporary-materialization-in-c17?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment75311600_44146960

Comment: Ah, so in this case it's because the temporary is being bound to the reference argument of the move constructor. Then it sounds like the first two steps would simply be swapped, or rather the first becomes part of the second: the operator is invoked, then the temporary is materialized to facilitate the move. It doesn't sound like anything is actually elided in this case as the compiler-generated move-assignment operator is not further moving the argument, but instead reads from its members.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a big change, just saying ;)

Comment: Right. So the benefit would be where such a move operator takes the argument and passes it as an rvalue reference somewhere else (move-construction or move-assignment) in which case the intermediate move-construction is not only guaranteed to be elided, but even no move-constructor is required to exist.

Comment: @MohamedHossam I added a section explaining why you see the pointer values that you do.

Comment: @cdhowie: Ok got it.. again thanks for this clarification